# Find the cross node for number of nodes in Gremlin?

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I have a number of nodes connected through intermediate node of other type. Like on picture
There are can be multiple middle nodes.
I need to find all the middle nodes for a given number of nodes and sort it by number of links between my initial nodes. In my example given A, B, C, D it should return node E (4 links) folowing node F (3 links). Is this possible? If not may be it can be done using multiple requests?

[image: Example graph]

Comment: Why is C not a "middle node"? Are the middle nodes marked at the start? If not, you need to tell us what makes it a "middle node"

Comment: Middle nodes doesn't mark at start. But C can't be middle node because it is in initial array of nodes. Also in OrientDB E and F are nodes from different class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [toy graph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Property-Graph-Model).
Let's assume vertex 1 and 6 are given:

```
g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()

m=[:]
g.v(1,6).both.groupCount(m)
m.sort{-it.value}
```

Sorted Map `m` contains:

```
==>v[3]=2
==>v[2]=1
==>v[4]=1
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but can you write your code using data from my example? I can't get how you code should be modified to use more than 2 vertex. Should I use g.v(1,6,5,4) like this?

Comment: Yes. `g.v(<your-first-vertex-id>,<your-second-vertex-id>, …)`

Comment: I've tried to run it from gremlin console like this: g.V('13:7','13:5','13:0','13:6').both.groupCount(m) But I've got error:
No signature of method: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException.V() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [13:7, 13:5, 13:0, 13:6]
Possible solutions: any(), wait(), find(), grep(), dump(), every() Also can you explain what m=[:] construction do?

Comment: Note that ```g.V``` is not the same as ```g.v```. ```m = [:]``` initializes an empty map. The code provided by Faber can be written as a one-liner: ```g.v(1,6).both.groupCount().cap().next().sort{-it.value}```

Comment: Thank you @DanielKuppitz This works like a charm. Can you, please tell me how can I modify it to find these cross nodes only of specific class?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OrientDB, thus I don't know how it stores the class. If it's just a simple property, add a ```.has()``` step. If it's more complex, use ```.filter()```.

Comment: Btw: More convenient than `g.v(1,6)` might be `g.v([1,6].toArray())` (passing a list of vertex identifiers). From docu: http://gremlindocs.com/#methods/graph-v